# How to write an array containing dictionaries to mongodb using mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have my data structured as `[{type: "advanced", price: 5000}]`. The schema type is set to `type: []`. When I query the data in my browser (using react) I get an array but the objects like `['[object Object],[object Object]']`. How can I save this data and retrieve it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try this as the schema:

```
type:[{type:String , price:Number }]
```

Comment: It still returns the same response

Comment: @Derek can you share more codes from the back nad front?

Comment: There's really a lot going on in the code especially in the front-end dont know which snippet to send. The focuse is on the back end (node js) where basically i'm just doing Schema.save() (which works).

Comment: I've figured out what's received in the backend is [object Object], [object Object], i guess the sending is where the problem is, so should i send the axios snippet?

Comment: Sure ,you can send whatever you think might be an issue

Comment: solution is to stringify the data before sending

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify(myobject)` when appending it to the form before sending